# Set value in jQuery Masked Textbox from MVC3 model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, maskedinput

I am using  jQuery Masked Input Plugin.

```
$("#txtBoxId").mask("###-##-####");
```

Everything works fine if I set the complete value from model i.e. `123-45-6789`.
But I want to display only the last inputs i.e. `6789`.

Is there any way to set the value of the textbox in the format `###-##-6789`?

Comment: tried with <code>**-**-6789</code> also but didn't work

Comment: how about something like this, `$("#txtBoxId").mask("###-##-" + @ViewBag.SomeValue);` just give it a try... (correct syntax error if any)

Comment: This would create mask as format ###-##-"somevalue".

Comment: Why not implement it as a set of auto tabbed inputs? http://www.rgagnon.com/jsdetails/js-0113.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
string input = " 123-12-1234  123-11-1235";

string pattern = @"(?:\d{3})-(?:\d{2})-(\d{4})";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "XXX-XX-$1");

Console.WriteLine(result); // XXX-XX-1234  XXX-XX-1235
```